# What music player works with ipod nano 7th generation?

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee, ipod, amarok, nano

Does anyone know of a music player that supports the ipod nano 7g? I know amarok doesn't, and I haven't had any success playing around with rhythm box or banshee. Any suggestions for how to get these or other players to work would be wonderful!

Comment: All of the music players you have tried work fine, you need [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) for them to recognise i0S devices.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Apple changed the FS type in the more recent iPods, e.g. Nano 7G, so that it is not compatible with gtkpod which is the engine for many of the Linux based players. The link below outlines a workaround to the issue. Note though that it involves tweaking the Nano's FS.

http://sourceforge.net/p/gtkpod/mailman/message/30329260/

Answer (score 1):

iTunes is not made to run natively on Linux, and Apple makes the iPods to only work with iTunes.  However, there is a way to get iTunes to run on linux.  Follow the instructions here:

http://ipod.about.com/od/advanceditunesuse/f/Downloading-Itunes-For-Linux.htm

Comment: Newer versions of ITunes may not work in WINE. You may want to use an older version. http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347

Answer (score 0):

iTunes I believe is the only supported music player that works with the ipod nano